# How to find min element using std::ranges::min in C++

Tags: c++, std-ranges

I tried to use C++ std::ranges library, and I wonder whether I can write more compact code like python. So I want to use ranges, but my code doesn't compile:

```
<source>:16:41: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::ranges::dangling')
   16 |     std::cout << "Shortest string: " << *shortest << std::endl;
      |
```

There is my code below:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> readFile(const std::string&);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = readFile("names.txt");

    // same as python code below:
    // min_len = min(len(s) for s in words)
    auto shortest = *std::ranges::min_element(words | std::views::transform([](const std::string& s) { return s.size(); }));
    std::cout << "Shortest string: " << shortest << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre], with all the compilation (and other) errors.

Comment: You haven't actually tested your Python code.

Comment: tip: translating from python to c++ is like translating from english to spanish, when you are native french, it doesnt make it much simpler. Different languages are different, using one language as model to write code in a different language fails more often than not

Comment: The issue with your code is that you pass a temporary `std::view` adaptor object as argument to `std::ranges::min_element`. This function will return an iterator into the temporary range which goes out of scope as the function finishes. You want an iterator into your original range `words`. To solve your issue, pass a comparator function of projection to `std::ranges::min_element` like @SH suggested in his answer. Here is a link using a projection: https://godbolt.org/z/fxvP5Kr71

Answer (score 4):

You can just use std::min_element which does exactly that:

```cpp
{
    std::vector<string> words = {"Hello","World","cpp"};

    auto shortest = std::min_element(words.begin(),words.end(),[](const string &s1,const string &s2) { return s1.size()<s2.size();});
    
    std::cout << "Shortest string: " << *shortest << std::endl; //will print "cpp"
}
```

In that case, change your comp function like I did here, so it has 2 arguments and compares their sizes.
Don't forget to include the algorithm header of course.
However if you really want to use range, the syntax is like this:

```cpp
auto shortest = std::ranges::min_element(words, [](const string& s, const string &s2) { return s.size()<s2.size(); });
```

You use the lambda the same way, with the 2 arguments.
as @康桓瑋 said you can use `std::ranges::size` instead of the lambda function.

Comment: OP is asking how to use `ranges`

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use lambda, you can use `ranges::size` as the projection

```
std::cout << *std::ranges::min_element(words, {}, std::ranges::size);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7r18cYj18)